# Why does the first database access for my Web API local database take 2 or more minutes?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a VS2013 WebAPI application that is using a database with a connection string like this:

```
 <add name="DbContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;
                      Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=xx;
                      Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;
                      AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\abcd.mdf;
                      Initial Catalog=abcd;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The first time the application runs it seems to take sometimes more than 2 minutes before it responds to a database request. Once started then it's okay.

I'm running against a local database on a machine with 8GB of memory.

Comment: I have exactly same problem. using mvc 4.0 Ef 6.0 dbfirst apporach and its taking 40 sec to load on the first time after that its very qucik .how can i fix that..any help would be appriciated..

Comment: LocalDB instances are not like other SQL Server instances - they spin down when not in use. The first time you connect to it, it's likely taking the time to spin up before responding to your request. If possible, you could try calling StartInstance for (localdb)\Projects at app startup time. This might help LocalDB begin initializing before your calls start coming in? See the API reference (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh217143.aspx) or the command line reference (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first time the application runs it seems to take sometimes more than 2 minutes before it 
>   responds to a database request. Once started then it's okay.

Because the first time it starts it has to:

- Start the .NET framework application and compile it.
- POSSIBLY attach the database (adttachdbfilename is really depreceated and bad practive - you should use hard attached databases).

The compile - step 1 - can take significant time, if the application is large. You can prime it and keep it running (google is your friend) but if it shuts down then the start will take time (again).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Maybe my question was not clear. The application itself takes about 90 seconds to start and then after this when I click on a button on a screen to do a database access then that's another 2 minutes. Can you explain what you mean when you say " (adttachdbfilename is really depreceated and bad practive - you should use hard attached databases)" Is there something different that I should be doing in my connect string?

Comment: @Melina Nt ocnnection string. Reading documentation. Attach the database to the server permanently, do not use user level attached databases.